# ruby rest_client exception handling

Tags: ruby, exception, rest-client

I'd like to do some HTTP REST requests in Ruby, using rest-client gem,

Following readme.md at https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client
I wrote this simple command line script, trying to catch exceptions in case of response codes differents from 2xx:

```
RestClient.get('http://thisurldoesnotexist/resource') { |response, request, result, &block|
case response.code
  when 200
    p "It worked !"
    response
  else
    response.return!(request, result, &block)
  end
}
```

Hi got this on stdout output:

```
/home/*****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /home/solyaris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:68:in `get'
    from prova_rest.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

How can i catch SocketError ?
where I'm wrong ?

thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback block is executed only when receiving some response from the server. In this case, the name resolving is failed so `RestClient.get` just throws an exception without entering the block. Thus just wrap your code within a `begin...end` construct.

```
begin
  RestClient.get('http://thisurldoesnotexist/resource') { |response, request, result, &block|
  case response.code
    when 200
      p "It worked !"
      response
    else
      response.return!(request, result, &block)
    end
  }
rescue SocketError => e
  # Handle your error here
end
```